# Converting char to integer causing seg fault

Tags: c

Take the below example from a project I'm working on. What I'm trying to do is take the this character from a strong, and store it in variable m. In the case, mORi is a string that contains L(5). I'm only interested in the this char (the 5 in this case). I'm able to capture that character using m, but when I try to convert it to an integer, my program seg faults. I'm assuming I'm exceeding some boundary somewhere. There must be something super simple missing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
char m;
m = mORi[2]; //trying to get third char from string
int mber = atoi(m); // seg faults here
```

I am getting the following warning when I compile:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘atoi’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

I'm unsure why it appears to be assuming it's an integer and not a char.

Comment: atoi needs a pointer to a string as it's input argument

Comment: Use `atoi(&mORi[2])`; that passes a string which is what `atoi()` requires — witness the warning.  `char` is promoted to `int`, but `atoi()` expects a pointer, so you're converting an `int` to a pointer which is not what you intended.  The compiler did try to help!

Comment: So i routinely struggle with pointers/addresss spaces... Is this like the puberty of programming? Just kind of comes with time? Happen to have any basic tutorials on them?

Comment: Sorry no tutorial. But you have to realize that pointer are nothing special. Instead of holding an interger or character, they hold a memory address. If you want to look at the value at a memory address you can use `*` to get the value at the memory address specified right to it. Other than that it's like everything in programming: practice.

Answer (score 4):

`atoi` converts a string (pointer to a `NULL` terminated char array), not a `char`. If you want to convert your `char` to an `int`, just subtract `'0'`:

```
char m;
m = mORi[2]; //trying to get third char from string
int mber = m - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative for using `atoi`:

```
char m[2];
m[0] = mORi[2]; //trying to get third char from string
m[1] = 0; // NULL-terminating
int mber = atoi(m); // OK
```